# Using plotly express to show image and plot with animation

Tags: python, plotly-python, plotly-express

I need some help making an animation with plotly express where each frame will include an image and a graph (preferably a plotly express graph) side by side. My goal is to have the animation be corresponding to time steps from each frame. Plotly express has an example of this with just images shown in the link below. But I do not know how to make a plotly express graph take the place of one of the images in the example.

The link below will lead you to the plotly express example for "Combining animations and facets"

Link to plotly for specific example: 'Combining animations and facets' (https://plotly.com/python/imshow/)

'''

```
from skimage import data, io
import plotly.express as px
data = io.imread("https://github.com/scikit-image/skimage-tutorials/raw/main/images/cells.tif")
data = data.reshape((15, 4, 256, 256))[5:]
fig = px.imshow(data, animation_frame=0, facet_col=1, binary_string=True)
fig.show()
```

'''

Update:

So I can make side my side plots with images but I'm having a difficult time with animating it. Below is my current code:

'''

```
imgR=np.random.rand(360,1000)
imgR2=np.random.rand(360,1000)
      
fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3,4,5], y=[4, 5, 6,7,8]),
    row=1, col=1
)

fig.add_trace(
    px.imshow(imgR).data[0],
    row=1, col=2
)
frames=[go.Frame(data=[go.Scatter(x=[3,5,2,5,3],y=[3,4,5,3,3]),px.imshow(imgR2).data[0]],traces=[0,1])]

fig.frames=frames
                 
button = dict(
             label='Play',
             method='animate',
             args=[None, dict(frame=dict(duration=50, redraw=False), 
                              transition=dict(duration=0),
                              fromcurrent=True,
                              mode='immediate')])

fig.update_layout(updatemenus=[dict(type='buttons',
                              showactive=False,
                              y=0,
                              x=1.05,
                              xanchor='left',
                              yanchor='bottom',
                              buttons=[button] )
                                      ],
                 width=800, height=500)
fig.update_layout(height=600, width=800, title_text="Side By Side Subplots")

fig.show()
```

'''

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of things you need to be systematic with

1. make sure each frame has a **name**
2. make sure each trace is using correct axes
3. build **sliders** from list of frames

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

imgR = np.random.rand(20, 40)

fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2)
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], y=[4, 5, 6, 7, 8]), row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(px.imshow(imgR).data[0], row=1, col=2)

frames = []
for i in range(5):
    if i > 0:
        np.random.shuffle(x)
        np.random.shuffle(y)
    # need to name the frame for slider, plus make sure both traces are using
    # correct axes
    frames.append(
        go.Frame(
            name=str(i),
            data=[
                go.Scatter(x=x, y=y),
                px.imshow(np.random.rand(20, 40) if i > 0 else imgR)
                .update_traces(xaxis="x2", yaxis="y2")
                .data[0],
            ],
        )
    )

# now have all parts to puild figure
figa = go.Figure(data=fig.data, frames=frames, layout=fig.layout)

# add slider
figa.update_layout(
    sliders=[
        {
            "active": 0,
            "currentvalue": {"prefix": "animation_frame="},
            "len": 0.9,
            "steps": [
                {
                    "args": [
                        [fr.name],
                        {
                            "frame": {"duration": 0, "redraw": True},
                            "mode": "immediate",
                            "fromcurrent": True,
                        },
                    ],
                    "label": fr.name,
                    "method": "animate",
                }
                for fr in figa.frames
            ],
        }
    ],
)
```

Comment: Thank you! this helps. I'm also trying to do another variation of this analysis with animations but I would like the functionality of turning the particular trace on or off in the legend. Do you have any insight on this? The link to that question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71426516/how-to-add-legend-for-picture